# Python EST API Multi Thread from List

Tags: python, json, multithreading, api

I've got a Python list of ~380 records I need to send to an API but it's slow doing it individually.  I currently can use this:

```
payload_length = len(payload)
for i in range(0, payload_length):
    send_contacts(payload[i])
```

To send an individual contacts but wondered if I could start x number of threads.  I read about asynchronous request and grequests but I can't get my head around the code.

I'd be grateful of any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm hoping this will help someone move from requests to grequests as this took me longer than it should have:

Original request:

```
print ("Sending stuff requests...")
r =  requests.post(url='https://rest.api.com/v1/lists/12345/contacts', data=json_payload, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization' : 'Basic '+ api_string}, timeout=5)
print(json.loads(r.text))
```

What I figured out was I can put in the URL in manually and in my "for u in urls" I've actually got a list of json payloads which get fired off all at once rather than multiple URLs.  I'm sure this is still super bad code but it was a quick and hacky fix to my issue:

```
print ("Sending stuff grequests...")
rs = (grequests.post('https://rest.api.com/v1/lists/12345/contacts', data=u[1], headers={'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Authorization' : 'Basic '+ api_string}) for u in urls)
responses = grequests.map(rs)
for response in responses:
    print(json.loads(response.text))
```